# Authorize Google Oauth without launching the browser

Tags: lambda, google-api, google-oauth, double-click

I am creating a lambda function to get data from Google API.
I get the following error:

> Failed to launch browser with "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?access_type=offline&response_type=code&client_id=XRARESRAS"

Is there a way that I can authorize the api access without launching the browser.
I am using `Google.apis.Doubleclicksearch.v2`

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766912/how-do-i-authorise-an-app-web-or-installed-without-user-intervention/19766913#19766913

Answer (score 1):

The way Oauth2 works is that a browser page is displayed to the user which they can approve your deny your application access to their data.  There is no way around that.  A user needs to approve your access and to do that they must see it in a browser.

If this account you are trying to connect to is your own then you should look into creating a service account and adding the service account email address as a user to  Search Ads 360.  However it will depend upon the language you are using wither or not you can use a service account they are intended mostly for server to server communication.